# How to avoid a permission error while loading an image

Tags: python, image, permissions, pygame

I have a images folder:

```
images
  |- some images.png
  |- grasses
     |- grass images.png
```

When i want to open an image, like:

```
for image_file_name in os.listdir("images/grasses"):
  image_file_id = image_file_name.split(".")[0]
  with open("images/grasses/" + image_file_name) as file:
    surface = pygame.image.load(file)
    surfaces[image_file_id] = surface
```

i get this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Rock Rain/Rock Rain.py", line 43, in <module>
     with open("images/" + image_file_name) as file:
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'images/grasses'
```

I checked out the permissions of this folder, but it was not the problem. What is the problem ?

Comment: Why are you removing the extension of the file with split? Try to eliminate this step and see if it works.

Comment: It is for saving the image to surfaces dict, it is not for loading image. so it did not work

Comment: The error line in the traceback is different than the code you show ("images/" verses "images/grassses"). Update one or the other so we have a more consistent view of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I understood my mistake. There was more than this which were loading images and the main problem was there. I was trying to load the grasses dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't filter the data you want to open. `os.listdir` lists everything in the directory, including other subdirectories. In your case, you listed "images" which includes the subdirectory "grasses" and you can't `open` directories. As a minimum, check file type and extension

```
for image_file_name in os.listdir("images/grasses"):
  image_file_id = image_file_name.split(".")[0]
  fullname = os.path.join("images/grasses", image_file_name)
  if fullname.endswith(".png") and os.path.isfile(fullname):
    with open(fullname, "rb") as file:
      surface = pygame.image.load(file)
      surfaces[image_file_id] = surface
```

Comment: Yes i have understood it but i did not use this, i used [file for file in os.listdir("images") if os.path.isfile("images/" + file)]. This solved problem but thanks for your answer